# Почему я получаю 400 Bad Request?

Tags: ajax, curl, веб-скрейпинг

При запросе курлом страницы сайта, я получаю и отображаю ее содержимое. На сайте есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую список продукции динамически подгружается по 20 штук, отследил в отладчике хрома и выявил, что есть некоторые параметры, которые скорее всего связаны с подгрузкой контента аяксом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При каждом нажатии page увеличивается. Правильно ли я понимаю, что это post-параметры? Если так, то я их передаю в запрос

```
$post = json_encode([
'act' => 'data-more',
'page' => '3', 
'eng' => '44536', 
'sys' => 'guest', 

]);

$html = request('http://www.site.ru', $post);
echo $html;
```

но получаю ошибку 400 Bad Request. Если вместо $post отправить null , то получаю искомую страницу но с 20 товарами. Как мне получить страницу хотя бы с 40 товарами? Подскажите пожалуйста в чем ошибка, почему получаю 400 Bad Request?

Вот функция request

```
function request( $url, $post = null ){
$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "UTF-8" );

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64)   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/tmp/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/tmp/cookie.txt');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
                 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8', 
                'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest',
                'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
                'Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
                'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
                'Connection:keep-alive',
                ]);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.site.ru');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);        

if( $post ){
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post );
}

if (($html = curl_exec($ch)) == false && $html == '')
{
    echo 'Ошибка curl: ' . curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close( $ch );
return $html;
}
```

Comment: что за функция request? Что в ней?

Comment: Дополнил вопрос функцией request

Answer (score 0):

Вы не указываете что отпраляете POST запрос, нужно ещё параметр дописать, так же вы данные передаете в `json`, это тоже не верно.
Данные передавайте в виде массива, а в `request` обрабатывайте через [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.http-build-query.php):

```
if( $post ){
    //Этого параметра у вас и не хватало
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
    //в $post лежит массив, ключи должны совпадать с полями формы
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post) );
}
```

Comment: Изменил и передаю в виде массива, но к сожалению получаю все тот же результат 400 Bad Request. Проверяю запросы скрипта в отладчике хрома и настораживает, что там нет post-данных.

Comment: @ZaurK куки точно в в файл пишутся? Остается только эта причина как по мне, что-то в куках должно быть ещё для правильного запроса

Comment: По крайней мере при каждом запросе куки обновляются

Comment: @ZaurK в этом может быть проблема, вы должны при входе на главную страницу сохранять куки в файл, а уже когда пытаетесь через POST забрать следующую страницу подставлять куки из файла, а не брать новые

Comment: Если идет запрос на страницу http://www.compel.ru/catalog/ic/analog/current-shunt-monitors, то опции CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR и CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE должны же ставить куки и тут же читать их?

Comment: Проверяю содержимое массива print_r($_POST); он пустой, ничего не уходит